# Is there a way to populate the menu for a Select dropdown from another channel field, but limit it to that entry

Tags: drop-down, pre-populate

Is there a way (most likely with a plugin) to populate a select dropdown channel field from another field within the same entry? What I'd like is to be able to add links and relate them to another field within the same entry.

Comment: Backend or front and a bit more info on what youre trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to populate it on the backend side of things. I have a grid field where I add chapters. I was hoping to have a field below where I can add links and associate them with a chapter. I would put it in the grid itself, but my grid is getting pretty big and the usability is getting bad when entering information. If you know a solution to that problem, it would solve my issue too.

Comment: Have you tried the relationship field..? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html